# Test Automation: TeamCity with Selenium and SOAPUI and Calabash

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, teamcity, soapui, calabash

We are building apps for iOS and Android. Currently we are experimenting with TeamCity for CI.

Currently we have various tools to help us in the Test automation.
1. Selenium: For testing the web interface
2. SOAPUI: For testing the web services
3. Calabash-iOS: For testing iOS app

This is the scenario that we have done successfully with TeamCity:
1. Developer commits code to BitBucket
2. TeamCity runs calabash
3. If calabash pass, TeamCity will build and give the artifacts

This is the scenario that I am trying to do so that I can achieve an end-to-end automated testing:

When developer commits his code to our Bitbucket git repository,

- TeamCity will trigger Calabash to run and check for the UI and the output of the details. On end,
- TeamCity will trigger Selenium to add data in the Back Office web. On end,
- TeamCity will trigger SOAP UI to check newly added data. On end,
- TeamCity will trigger Calabash to check the newly added data

Has anyone tried this before or can give me an idea on how I can approach this?

Comment: Regarding the SOAP-UI part,are you using the SOAP-UI API for testing the web services part?

Comment: Yes! We are using SOAP-UI API for testing the web services

Answer (score 1):

You can setup different builds for each step since you can trigger builds via simple GET requests triggered by a script. [TeamCity Accessing Server by HTTP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP)

We run a similar setup. Basically we have one build kick off the Selenium/SoapUI scripts. That build doesn't wait for the job to finish, it just kicks it off. Then in our Selenium/SoapUI tests as the last step we hit the URL for the next build that picks up reports etc.